# Issue with ; separated file, negative sign is misplaced, character to numeric conversion coercion

Tags: r, dataframe, coercion, data-cleaning

I want to convert all the misplaced -ve sign in data to prefix - sign and convert data to numeric.

I have a data frame such as all these data is being read from a ; separated file, which has a wrong separation. I need to clean this data and convert it into numeric class where 4-,1-,8- becomes -4,-1,-8 and gets treated as -ve numbers.

My data frame is like:

```
data.frame(a=c("1","1-","2","4-"),b= c("2","3-","4","5"),c=c("3-","6-","3","8"),d=c("5","9","9-","6"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires creating a `sub` regex-pattern for numbers `0-9` or a decimal point followed by a minus sign in a character class with arbitrary number of repeats, and replacing the minus signwith a preceding minus sign before passing to as.numeric. This has no safety tests. If you have not yet deleted your earlier question that had only a picture of the data, then you should go back and delete it now.

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=c("1","1-","2","4-"),
                    b= c("2","3-","4","5"),
                   c=c("3-","6-","3","8"),
                   d=c("5","9","9-","6"))
 lapply(df1, function(col) as.numeric( sub("([0-9.]+)[-]", "-\\1", col) ) )
#---- result looks OK  ---
$a
[1]  1 -1  2 -4

$b
[1]  2 -3  4  5

$c
[1] -3 -6  3  8

$d
[1]  5  9 -9  6
# --- now replace the original df1 structure with those values ---
 df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(col) as.numeric( sub("([0-9.]+)[-]", "-\\1", col) ) )
#---- check for success----
> str(df1)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ a: num  1 -1 2 -4
 $ b: num  2 -3 4 5
 $ c: num  -3 -6 3 8
 $ d: num  5 9 -9 6
```

Comment: Thanks, perfect that's what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Switch the 2 capture group (numeric and the negative sign) where `df` is your data.frame, then cast to numeric:

```
 sapply(df,function(x){ as.numeric(sub("([0-9.]*)(-)$","\\2\\1",x)) })
```